# AVSpeechSynthesizer stutter during UI update

Tags: ios, multithreading, avspeechsynthesizer

When `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is in progress of speaking a sentence, and a UI change is happening (for example a `ViewController` is pushed, a `UIButton`'s title is changed, ...), the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is stuttering.

All my UI changes are in a `dispatch_async` block. I have to do this, because otherwise the UI is not updating correctly.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.aButton setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
});
```

I have tried running `speakUtterance` on the main thread and on the background thread, but it doesn't matter, the stuttering keeps happening.

If there are no UI changes during the `speakUtterance`, there is no problem at all.

Is this a bug in `AVSpeechSynthesizer`? Am I missing something in regards to threading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found out what happened.

The function that calls the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` executed this code everytime:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                             withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers
                                                   error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Turns out this is totally not necessary and will cause the hiccups and stuttering in `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.

So it had nothing to do with doing UI stuff during speaking after all.

Comment: What was your solution, though? Did you only move the `setCategory:withOptions:error` call to somewhere else, or did you also move `setActive:error:` so that it wasn't being called every time?

Comment: @Nate I call `setCategory:withOptions:error` and `setActive:error:` once in another method indeed. It's not called anymore when I need the AVSpeechSynthesizer.